# Render wp_editor input in theme file using get_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a meta box with wp_editor other than the main content editor.

```
    public function add_custom_meta_boxes() {
        add_meta_box(
            'ux_page_header',
            __( 'Page Header', 'ux' ),
            array($this, 'ux_render_page_header'),
            'page',
            'normal',
            'core'
        );
    }

    public function ux_render_page_header() {
        $page_header =  get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'page_header' , true ) ;
        wp_editor( 
            htmlspecialchars_decode($page_header), 
            'ux_page_header', 
            $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'page_header') 
        );
    }

    public function ux_save_post_data($post_id) {

        if( !empty($_POST['page_header']) ) {
            $data = htmlspecialchars($_POST['page_header']);
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'page_header', $data );
        }
    }
```

But when I am retrieving this data, it just prints the html code. How to render this html?

```
$header = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_header', true ); 
echo $header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the info here: `$data = htmlspecialchars($_POST['page_header']);` the data is encoded using `htmlspecialchars` so to render the content as HTML when calling `get_post_meta`, you will need to decode it:

```
$header = htmlspecialchars_decode(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_header', true ));
echo $header;
```